# What is KB890830? It has been hanging since 2010 and now it is hanging on my Windows10 x64 PC in late 2021

Tags: windows-update

Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - v5.95 (KB890830)
Status: Installing - 0%

Been that way now for a good 45 minutes.

What causes the hang?  I see [postings from 2010](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-stuck-at-malicious-removal-tool/c6027348-48a7-4c8a-90fc-c9cb98b92064?auth=1&page=2) where the same issue is reported. Are the KB numbers recycled?

P.S. Troubleshooter couldn't identify the problem.

Comment: I have that update here from this November just past. It normally runs and completes in less than 15 minutes. Leave if for a while (another hour) and then restart your computer.

Comment: Are you using a slow HDD?

Comment: By the way, this update (Malicious Software Removal) is part of most big Windows Updates. I have seen it go by lots of times.

Comment: It's *scanning the system*, which takes some time. Ignore the notice, and use the PC while it's being scanned... though it might be a bit slow.

Comment: @Mokubai: No, it's a solid-state drive that's been working fine. The malicious software removal tool hasn't ever hung up like this before.

Comment: @John:  I did as you suggested.  Upon reboot several other pending updates installed quickly and the Malicious Software Removal Tool was gone.  Then when I checked once again for updates, Malicious Software Removal Tool reappeared and it was once again "Installing - 0%" but after about 15 minutes it finished. So it seems the PC is over that particular hump.